# WCF: where to initialize SignalR?

Tags: wcf, signalr-hub

I have a WCF Service which can be installed by 3 ways:
1. in IIS
2. Window Service Host
3. Console Host

I'd like to use SignalR Hub in this service to provide full-duplex connections for the client apps.

Where I need to do SignalR initialization which can be suitable for any of 3 installation ways?
What is the best place in the WCF service for it?

Comment: Depends on how you are packaging your service...is it OWin?

Comment: I am going to use it as described here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b

Comment: If you want unified initialization you should be using owin/katana. Look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745865.aspx

Comment: 2 Tom Redfern: thank you, but there is key phrase is "A Console Application Is All You Need To Get Started". What can I do in case IIS wcf installation ?

Comment: @Oleg - owin can be configured to run in IIS very easily, by specifying the following appSettings in your web.config: `<add key="owin:appStartup" value="MyStartupClass" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />`

Comment: thank you Tom, please add the answer and I will mark it

Comment: Why not try it in init.CS file. It gets called on initialization